# How to do not user input decimal separator from keyboard  if user inputted decimal separator before

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, decimal

I have plugin, jQuery format number. But it’s not good. I want it to *not* input the decimal separator if the user inputted the decimal separator already.

Examples:

- `122.222,555,,,,..` should become `122.222,555`
- `122,222.555 ..,,,,` should become `122,222.555`

Here’s my plugin:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options)
    {
        options = $.extend({}, {
            thousands: '.',
            decimal: ','
        }, options);

        this.keyup(function()
        {
            $(this).val(function(el, val)
            {
                val = val.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '').split(options.decimal);
                val[0] = val[0].replace(options.decimal === '.' ? /,/g : /\./g, '');
                val[0] = val[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1" + options.thousands);
                return val.join(options.decimal);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

and here html:

```
<input id="txt" size="40" type="text">
<input id="new" size="40" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#txt').myPlugin();
    $('#new').myPlugin({thousands:',',decimal:'.'});
</script>
```

Comment: could you reprhase your question ? Is it a plugin that you have made or a already finished plugin ?

Comment: @minh Your examples are not sufficient. What do you expect for: `123,456.456,789`, `1,2,3`, `123.456,7891`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you to know there is a `.toLocaleString()` function.